# What does a static method/variable actually reference in java if an object has not been initialized?

Tags: java, class, object, static, static-methods

I understand the basic differences between static and instance methods, but I was wondering this for my CS final as it is not included in our book: what is your code actually referencing when you call a static method?

```
FooClass.staticMethod();
```

I am guessing it must initialize the class and then call the method, but that would mean that it isn't *really* static because its still referencing an object and not the class. Any explanations are appreciated as I really want a greater understanding of this topic, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FooClass` in your example is not an object, it's just an identifier telling the Java compiler what class contains `staticMethod`. It's true that a program referencing a class causes that class to be loaded and initialized (and also creates an object to represent that class, which is accessible via `FooClass.class`), but that doesn't mean that `staticMethod` is actually an instance method of a class object. It isn't. `this` has no meaning inside it.

(In fact, at the lowest level, the bytecode instruction for calling a static method is different from the one for calling an instance method.)

Comment: Offtopic: what happens you reach 500K? Is there some party somewhere? And the person upvoting you over 500K does he/she get a gold badge for doing so? If not, why not?

Comment: @GhostCat: LOL I don't know. At 100k, 200k, and (IIRC) 250k I got swag. Don't think there's been anything since. Meanwhile, I'm just waiting for [Jon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) to break the display (again) when he tops 1M.

Comment: I know, but that will be some more waiting. In my wildest dreams I hope reaching 100K before he reaches 1M. On the other hand, I am not sure if three more years at my current pace are really worth it.